# DownloadService loadResource caching

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

I'm wanting to use loadResource() to load a jar into the cache for my jnlp application. But it is not clear from the doc whether this method will always attempt to go to the server for the jar, or whether it will use a version that was previously downloaded.

My first thought was to use isResourceCached() and only then call loadResource() if it wasn't cached. But I discovered that although the jar was in the cache from a previous download, it doesn't get added to the classpath (I'm assuming from my observations).

So my question is: can I always call loadResource() and assume that it will get it the first time and then re-use it thereafter?